# Как сделать запрос к базе в yii2?

Tags: mysql, yii2

Есть две таблицы, `album(id, atitle, collect)` и `photo(id, ftitle, status)`.

В альбоме может храниться несколько фото, причем одно и то же фото может принадлежать нескольким альбомам одновременно. Также таблица фото имеет поле `status`, если равно 1, то фото видно, если 0 то не видно. 
Поле `collet` будет содержать массив из `id` фото в альбоме (кстати удачный ли это выбор или лучше делать связь в таблицах?).

Подскажите, как правильно сделать запрос в yii2, чтобы вывести список альбомов, в каждом из которых все фотографии имеют `status 1`?

Comment: При чем тут yii, за вас надо просто SQL запрос написать?

Comment: Мне именно  в yii2 как подобные запросы делаются хочется увидеть. Тут вопрос даже больше в самой организации: лучше ли делать таблицы связанными по вешнему ключу или просто сохранять в поле collect массив и с ним потом сверять